# Python is throwing error, "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: javascript, python, axios

I am submitting information via my html form and would like for JS axios to handle form submission to notify my API about the incoming data. However, I keep receiving a typeerror telling me, "nonetype object is not subscriptable." Here is my code:

Python route I am sending data to

```
@app.route("/api/cupcakes", methods=["POST"])
def create_cupcake():
    new_cupcake = Cupcake(flavor=request.json["flavor"], size=request.json["size"],
                          rating=request.json["rating"], image=request.json["image"])
    db.session.add(new_cupcake)
    db.session.commit()

    response_json = jsonify(cupcake=new_cupcake.serialize())
    return (response_json, 201)
```

HTML FORM

```
    <form action="/api/cupcakes" method="post">

        <label for="flavor">Flavor:</label>
        <input type="text" name="flavor"><br>

        <label for="size">Size:</label>
        <input type="text" name="size"><br>

        <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100"
            name="rating" placeholder="Enter a rating"><br>

        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="url" name="image" placeholder="Enter an image url"><br>

        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit Cupcake">
    </form>
```

JS

```
async function postCupcake() {
    let res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/cupcakes',
        data: {
        flavor: flavor,
        size: size,
        rating: rating,
        image: image
        },
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    console.log(res)
}


$(".btn").submit(function(event) {
    postCupcake()
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Here is a photo of my error

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is most likely because of `Content-Type`. By default axios uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` **Content-Type** header on HTTP POST requests. So try changing the content type to '`application/json`'

```
async function postCupcake() {
    let res = await axios.post('/api/cupcakes', {
        flavor: flavor,
        size: size,
        rating: rating,
        image: image
    },headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    console.log(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, that doesn't seem to have solved the issue. I am still receiving the same error

Comment: @rudehlabya Can you try printing `request.mimetype` in the flask function?